# Headers in GET request using Supplier<> in spring cloud function

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-function

Like using Message<> we get the headers in Function<>, Is it possible to get Headers inside Supplier<> in spring cloud function?

Comment: Hi Oleg Zhurakousky , can you please provide some input?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Supplier creates the data, so you can create anything you want and if inside such supplier (`Supplier<Message<?>>`) you are making Http request, then you can copy any http headers into produced message headers.

Comment: What i meant was in case of Function<Message<?>,Output>, we can get the headers in the message and that we can use inside the Function block but can we do similar kind in case of Supplier as supplier doesn't take any input and only returns a result?

Comment: I am not following. You just said it yourself `supplier doesn't take any input`, so where would you expect the headers to come from?